# Replace last occurences of string in lines between two strings

Tags: regex, replace, pcre

I'm trying to build a regex that would enable me to replace the last comma on multiple lines between two specific strings.

Sample text:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(SomeForm, BaseForm)
    ON_COMMAND(CID_ButtonAction, OnButtonAction)
    ON_NOTIFY_EX(CID_Notify, 0, OnNotify)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Desired output:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(SomeForm, BaseForm)
    ON_COMMAND(CID_ButtonAction, &ThisClass::OnButtonAction)
    ON_NOTIFY_EX(CID_Notify, 0, &ThisClass::OnNotify)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Replacing the last comma on a line is easy enough:

find `(,)([^,]*?)$`

and replace with `(?1,&ThisClass\:\:\2)`.

I was also able to build a regex that matches everything between `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` and `END_MESSAGE_MAP`.

```
(?<=BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP)(.*\R)*(?=END_MESSAGE_MAP)
```

The question is - how do I put these two together so that I can only replace between these two strings?

Comment: PCRE, sorry for omitting that, added a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
(?:^\h*BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP|(?!\A)\G)(?:.*\R)+?.*\K(,\h*)(?=(?:.*\R)+^END_MESSAGE_MAP)
```

And replace it by:

```
$1&ThisClass::
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrXug7/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. By placing negative lookahead `(?!\A)` we make sure that `\G` doesn't match at the start of the string.
- `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match.
- Lookahead condition in the end `(?=...)` is to make sure that we have `END_MESSAGE_MAP` ahead of us.

Comment: not entirely, it works perfectly in the demo but in Notepad++(uses boost regex as engine) it matches only the first occurrence for some reason

Comment: As you mentioned pcre this reged is using pcre features. Make sure you have multi line mode on

Comment: From what I read in documentation Notepad++ is supposed to support PCRE by using boost regex as engine. The problem seems to be the /g flag which cannot be enabled in Notepad++.

Comment: Exactly the same problem as the one in the answer, only first occurence is captured and replaced...you can replicate what I'm seeing in Notepad++ when you disable /g in regex101.com

Comment: `/g` is required here since we are capturing multiple occurrences using `\G`. I don't have `Notepad++` but I am sure they will have a way to enable global mode.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that in n++. I'll have a look for another tool...any advice on that? Preferably windows, linux is fine too.